# conenu в total commander

Tags: консоль, totalcommander, conemu

Всем доброго времени суток я добавил в total commander в панель conenu но она не открывает текущий каталог какие мне параметры передать ? В настройках conenu по умолчанию стоит git bash

Comment: открыть текущий каталог. параметр: /dir "%P"

Comment: Спасибо помогло